# The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x) f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$. Find all possible functions $f$.

Tags: functional-equations

The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$f(x) f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$$ for all real numbers $x$ and $y$. Find all possible functions $f$.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: One solution is 1+x

Comment: Why don't you add some context, like where did that come from, maybe a book or a teacher, or you just invented it yourself, taking some property of some function to investigate whether that identifies it? And why don't you add some background, so we can know what answer you can or cannot digest? Given it's a rather simple case, and you didn't even try anything, you must be a newby in functional equations.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot write the whole answer. Here are hints for you.

Compute $f(0)$ by taking $x=y=0$
If $f(0)=0$ then choose $y=0$...
If $f(0)=1$ then find $a$ such that $f(a)=0$ ( $a \in \{1,-1\}$). Then choose $y=a$ deduces the results.

Thanks for the comments. There are 2 solutions.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is not a solution, there are only two of them.

Comment: Thanks, I did not recheck it. Yes there are 2 solutions.