# What are the possible functions satisfying functional equation $f(x) f(y) = f(x + y) + xy$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I was able to find that $f(0)=1$ by setting $y=0$ to have $f(x)f(0)=f(x)$. DIviding on both sides, I was left with $f(0)=1. I still don't know how I can find all the possible functions and how I can use this.

Comment: Seems like $f(x)=1+x$ and $f(x)=1-x$ are the solutions but I don't see how to show them yet.

Comment: If you don't add some context (how did you find $f(0)=1$, say), your question will be closed, exactly as this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687605/the-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-satisfies-fx-fy-fx-y-x#comment7578799_3687605

Comment: What is the domain of $f?$

Comment: @SahibaArora The domain is all real numbers for both $x$ and $y$

Comment: @Cheez That information belongs in the question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you meant $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$P(x,y) \implies f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)+xy$$
$$P(x,0) \implies f(x)f(0)=f(x) \implies f(0)=1$$
Since $f(x)=0$ is not a solution, and we can replace $x$ by $a$ such that $f(a) \ne 0$, Now
$$P(1,-1) \implies f(1)f(-1)=0$$
Case 1: $f(1)=0$
$$P(x,1) \implies f(x+1)+x=0 \iff f(x)=1-x$$
Case 2: $f(-1)=0$
$$P(x,-1) \implies f(x-1)-x=0 \iff f(x)=x+1$$